# How do I initiate a user mouse-driven move or resize for custom window borders on Windows on a borderless window when the event comes to a child?

Tags: winapi, events, user32

I have a borderless window whose sole child, which is always the size of the window, is a third party component. That component wants to be able to notify me, when a `WM_MOUSEDOWN` has occurred in certain areas that is up to its discretion, to move or resize the window (as if it wasn't borderless). It also wants to decide the event to use in question.

Because the window is borderless and the child window has already received the mouse message, I don't think I would be able to override `WM_NCHITTEST`, would I? (Or in other words, does the parent window always get `WM_NCHITTEST` before my child gets `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`? Or only upon first activation/during a capture?)

GTK+ used to call `DefWindowProc()` with `WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN` to manually trigger that modal event loop. Is this the way to do it?

What about `SC_MOVE` in `WM_SYSCOMMAND`? Is that only for keyboard-driven window moves and resizes, not mouse-driven ones?

Or am I going to have to do this manually? I know it's a modal loop of its own that uses one of the message filter constants, and I know that Aero Snap would need to be done manually, at the least.

I need to do this on Windows Vista or higher.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your parent window is border-less and completely covered by the child window, the parent will not receive `WM_NCHITTEST` by default.  All `WM_NCHITTEST` messages will be received by the child first.

However, you can still allow the user to resize your parent window normally with a little extra coding.  There are a few different ways you can handle this:

1. subclass the child window to intercept the `WM_NCHITTEST` message.  When received, pass the message to the child's default message handler first, and if it returns `HTCLIENT` and the screen coordinates provided in `lParam` are within an area of the parent window that you want to use for resizing, return `HTTRANSPARENT` instead.  That will cause `WM_NCHITTEST` to be sent to the parent window next, which can then process `WM_NCHITTEST` and return one of the following values depending on the type of resize you want:

   ```
   HTBOTTOM
   HTBOTTOMLEFT
   HTBOTTOMRIGHT
   HTLEFT
   HTRIGHT
   HTTOP
   HTTOPLEFT
   HTTOPRIGHT
   ```
2. in the child window's mousedown event, convert the provided client coordinates of the mouse into screen coordinates, and then call `ReleaseCapture()` and send a `WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN` message to the parent window, setting `wParam` to one of the values mentioned above, and `lParam` to the screen coordinates.
3. in the child window's mousedown event, call `ReleaseCapture()` and send a `WM_SYSCOMMAND` message to the parent window, setting `wParam` to `SC_SIZE` plus the desired value below, and `lParam` to 0:

   ```
    SC_SIZE_HTLEFT = 1
    SC_SIZE_HTRIGHT = 2
    SC_SIZE_HTTOP = 3
    SC_SIZE_HTTOPLEFT = 4
    SC_SIZE_HTTOPRIGHT = 5
    SC_SIZE_HTBOTTOM = 6
    SC_SIZE_HTBOTTOMLEFT = 7
    SC_SIZE_HTBOTTOMRIGHT = 8
   ```

Either way will allow the parent window to resize normally, and everything that involves (mouse tracking, snapping, etc), except for one thing.  #1 tricks the OS into thinking the user had moused over the parent window directly, and so it allows the OS to provide visual feedback about which "sizing border" is being used.  #2 and #3 will not provide any visual feedback, so you would have to handle that manually via `SetCursor()` if desired.

If you want to allow the user to drag the parent window around without resizing it, you can either:

1. subclass the child `WM_NCHITTEST` messages to return `HTTRANSPARENT` in the appropriate area, and then have the parent window process `WM_NCHITTEST` to return `HTCAPTION`.
2. in the child window's mousedown event, call `ReleaseCapture()` and send a `WM_SYSCOMMAND` message to the parent window, setting `wParam` to `SC_DRAGMOVE` (which is undocumented, but its value is `$F012`, aka `SC_MOVE + 2`), and `lParam` set to 0.

Comment: So my only option is to use `WM_NCHITTEST` anyway? I'm only asking because right now the signal to drag-resize is documented to be sent during the `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` handler; I can change the API no problem though. Would the low-bits trick work with `SC_SIZE` as well?

Comment: `WMNCHITTEST` is not your *only* option. And yes, `SC_SIZE` has a similar low-bits trick.  I have updated my answer.

Comment: Cool, thanks. And just for the sake of completeness with the standard way, would there ever be a situation where subclassing the child's `WM_NCHITTEST` wouldn't be enough?

Comment: Subclassing `WM_NCHITTEST` would be enough to handle both situations seemlessly, but using `SendMessage()` in the child's mousedown event would probably be quicker to code.